# Using aggregates to replace nested for-loops

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops, aggregation

```
    for (Sample i : DATA) {
        for(Sample ii : DATA){

            if(i.getID() == ii.getID()){
                // Do nothing.
            }else {
                i.addMatch(new Match(ii.getID()));
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a `List<Sample>` and each `Sample` contains a `List<Match>`. `List<Match>` is a collection of `Samples` matched to another `Sample`. Thus, `List<Match>` contains all original samples minus the one they are being compared to.

**Q1:** Are aggregate operations useful here? If not, how can I know when they are?

**Q2:** If yes, what would be the appropriate way to write that?

**EDIT:** [Java lesson on Aggregate Operations.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/)

Comment: Am I right that you want to replace your construct with a `Stream`?

Comment: @Flown I edited my question. Hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: `Aggregate operations process elements from a stream, not directly from a collection. Consequently, they are also called stream operations.`. So this means you want to replace your nested loops - as I said before - with `Stream` operations.

Comment: Yes. That is what I am refering to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q1**: Are aggregate operations useful here? If not, how can I know when they are?

They're partially useful in your case. If you want to iterate over a `Collection` it's always better to use the old-fashioned foreach loop because it doesn't have the overhead of creating a `Stream` pipeline. But your inner loop fits perfect for `Stream` processing because you filter and map every element.

> **Q2**: If yes, what would be the appropriate way to write that?

```
for (Sample sample : DATA) {
    DATA.stream()
       .mapToInt(Sample::getId).filter(id -> id != sample.getId()).mapToObj(Match::new)
       .forEach(m -> sample.addMatch(m));
}
```